# The state of a pointer after deallocation

Tags: c, memory-management

What does the pointer of a dynamically allocated memory points to after calling the `free()` function.
Does the pointer points to NULL, or it still points to the same place it pointed before the deallocation.
does the implementation of free() has some kind of standard for this, or it's implemented differently in different platforms.

```
uint8_t * pointer = malloc(12);
printf("%p", pointer); // The current address the pointer points to
free (pointer);
printf("%p", pointer); // must it be NULL or the same value as before ?
```

Edit:
I know that the printf will produce the same results, I just want to know if I can count on that on different implementations.

Comment: Why do you want to printf after free()? Why count on it?

Comment: @VinayakGarg: I think it's more of a debugging print statement.

Comment: @VinayakGarg I'm programming an embedded device, and in a certain task I allocate memories. There is a problem once I get an interrupt which is higher priority and needs also to allocate memory. I need to deallocate the previously allocated memory without knowing if it succeeded in allocation or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard (6.2.4/2 of C99):

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points
>   to reaches the end of its lifetime.

In practice, all implementations I know of will print the same value twice for your example code. However, it is *permitted* that when you free the memory, the pointer value itself becomes a trap representation, and the implementation does something strange when you try to use the value of the pointer (even though you don't dereference it).

Supposing that an implementation wants to do something unusual, a hardware exception or program abort would be the most plausible I think. You probably have to imagine an implementation/hardware that does a lot of extra work, though, so that every time a pointer value is loaded into a register, it somehow checks whether the address is valid. That could be by checking it in the memory map (in which case I suppose my hypothetical implementation would only trap if the whole page containing the allocation has been released and unmapped), or some other means.

Answer (score 5):

The pointer value is not modified.  You pass the pointer (memory address) *by value* to `free()`.  The `free()` function does not have access to the `pointer` variable, so it cannot set it to `NULL`.

The two `printf()` calls should produce identical output.

Comment: Can the downvote troll please explain the reason for their vote?  Thanks.

Comment: I guess either somebody *really* likes my answer, or I have a downvote coming any moment now...

Comment: Yeah, the spec-nazis tend to downvote answers on a technicality that makes them incorrect in theory, but correct just about everywhere in practice.  :S  At any rate, I think we can all agree that using a pointer value after you have freed it is a very bad thing to do, no matter which C implementation you are using.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but reading the freed pointer could *theoretically* cause an invalid address trap on some hardware (with dedicated address registers).

Comment: @BoPersson How would such an environment handle the code `void * foo = malloc(10); void * bar = foo; free(foo);` -- is `bar` set to a trap value as well?

Comment: @cdhowie - That would be the effect. Even though the pointers themselves are unchanged, their values might become invalid. When deallocating a large block on a segmented memory system (16-bit Windows for example), the entire segment might be unmapped, or the segment size might be adjusted so the address is now outside the valid range.

Comment: @BoPersson If the pointers are unchanged, then in what sense is my answer incorrect?  I don't think I've contradicted your statement.

Comment: @cdhowie - *If* the printf statements display anything, it will likely be the same address. But it might also terminate the program.

Answer (score 1):

`free()` only deallocates the memory. The pointer is still pointing to the old location (dangling pointer), which you should manually set to `NULL`.

Setting the pointer to `NULL` is a good practice. As the memory location may be reused for other object, you may be able to access and modify data which doesn't belong to you. This is especially hard to debug, since it won't produce a crash, or produce crash at some point which is irrelevant. Setting to `NULL` will guarantee a re-producible crash if you ever access the non-existent object.

Comment: Changing the code to `{ uint8_t * pointer = malloc(12); ... free(pointer); }` is far better practice than setting it to null, though. You can't use a dangling pointer if you make sure the pointer goes out of scope as soon as it becomes dangling.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in C++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int *a=new int;
    *a=5;
    cout<<*a<<" "<<a<<"\n";
    delete a;
    *a=45;
    cout<<*a<<" "<<a<<"\n";
}
```

The output was something like this

```
5 0x1066c20
45 0x1066c20
```

Running once more yielded a similar result

```
5 0x13e3c20
45 0x13e3c20
```

Hence it seems that in gcc the pointer still points to the same memory location after deallocation. 
Moreover we can modify the value at that location.